# View not recognizing mouse entered event when near border

Tags: java, javafx

I have had a strange problem that when near the border my view is not recognizing mouse events.

[image]

This is what it should look like. As you can see the cursor has changed as it is detecting hover with the white bar.

[image]

However when the element is close to the border it is not detecting the hover on the white bar. Why is this happening.

note:
The end of the blue box is the end of my window. This is my code changing the cursor.

```
settingsSeperator.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.E_RESIZE); //Change cursor to hand
    });
settingsSeperator.setOnMouseExited((event) -> {
        scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT); //Change cursor to hand
    });
```

edit:
What I am showing is a blue VBox that I am making resizeable through the white separator being dragged. My problem is that the white separator is not recognizing any mouse events when it is near the border of the view, so when the blue VBox has a width of zero. As a note, their structure is that both the separator and VBox are in an Hbox. I have created a workaround already, however it does is not a complete solution to the problem. Also to be more specific I am trying to make the separator recognize mouse events when near the border.

Comment: Your provided information in the question is not enough to understand the scenario. You need to clarify what you are doing, what elements you have used to implement, and the behavior you expect.

Comment: @IREmon done with the edits